# Join transactions table to an open ended table of labor rates as they change over time (supersedence)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of transactions (for labor) --

```
declare @transactions table (transactions varchar(36) not null, units decimal(12,2) not null
                            ,professionals varchar(36), trandate datetime not null
                            ,nobilldate datetime, primary key (transactions)
                            )
```

And a table of labor rates over time:

```
declare @rates table (rates varchar(36) not null, professionals varchar(36) not null
                        ,rate decimal(12,2) not null, effectivedate datetime not null
                        ,primary key (rates)
                        )
```

This comes from an application, so I have no ability to modify tables (other than maybe adding an index).
You'll note the rate table only has an effectivedate -- no end date.  Effectively "it's this rate until it is superseded".

You'll note the transactions table has a transaction date (transdate) and a nobill date (nobilldate) which is effectively a write-off.  Of course not everything is written off, so the nobilldate *can be null* and most often is null.  I need to calculate the value of the time (rate * units) when it was nobilled (if it was nobilled).

My approach has been to create a table variable that is basically the rate table but adding an "end date" to it.  I then use that table to join based on the nobilldate being between the effectivedate and the enddate (inclusive) --

```
declare @rates_t table (professionals varchar(36) not null, rate decimal(12,2) not null
                        ,effectivedate datetime not null, enddate datetime not null
                        , primary key (professionals, rate, effectivedate, enddate))

insert into @rates_t
select rp.professionals, rp.rate, rp.effectivedate
    ,min(isnull(rp2.effectivedate, '3000-01-02')) - 1 enddate -- 1/1/3000 represents "and into the future"
from (
    select *
    from @rates
) rp
left outer join (
    select *
    from @rates
) rp2
    on rp2.effectivedate > rp.effectivedate
    and rp2.professionals=rp.professionals
group by rp.professionals,rp.rate,rp.effectivedate


select t.transactions, r.rate * t.units value
from @transactions t
inner join @rates_t r
    on r.professionals = t.professionals
    and t.nobilldate >= r.effectivedate
    and t.nobilldate <= r.enddate
    and t.nobilldate is not null
where t.nobilldate < '2020-04-01'
    and t.nobilldate >= '2019-05-05'
```

This all works fine.  But it *takes forever*.  The rate table has 3300 entries (200 different professionals, 70 years of rate changes).  The transactions table has 7,000,000 entries.  This query is generally being used on transactions over the last 18 months, of which there are about 100,000 entries.  Of those, 8,000 entries have been nobilled.

The execution plan says the Key Lookup on the Transactions table costs 91%.

I'm looking for ideas/experience with this type of superseding table.  Here are some ideas I haven't tried yet:

- Create a table variable for the transactions table so I'm only joining the 8,000 nobilled entries instead of the 7,000,000
- Join the rate table directly (twice) instead of creating the @rate_t table with an end date.
- CTE?  But I don't really think this would change the execution plan or have any performance impact -- it's more of a way to write the query that's easier to understand.
- Reduce the number of entries in the @rate_t table that is created by eliminated professionals that aren't referenced in the last 18 months and eliminated anything with an end date older than the oldest transaction we care about.  *But* why would this perform better than the inner join?  Indexing?

Before I put in the effort to try random different approaches, I thought I'd see if anyone out there has advice.

Comment: What SQL Server version are you on? Also, a quick read of this will probably help. https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/table-variables/

Comment: SQL 2012 for now.

Comment: Well a CTE would actually change the execution plan because in SQL 2012 cardinality estimations on number of rows in a table variable is... 1. Yep, 1 row. Here is a good article. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/think-twice-before-using-table-variables . If i were starting this task I would do a select into statement to a temp table, add a clustered index on the joining columns and look at the execution plan.

Comment: <whine> But I *hate* temp tables. <sigh>  The simplified query took 1 minute using the table variable.  It took 7 seconds using a temp table.

Comment: I meant the CTE wouldn't be different than just joining the rate table directly.  I knew it would be different than using the table variable.

Comment: I guess from that perspective I should be able to just join the @rates_t query directly as a subquery.

Comment: As a rule of thumb I do not use table variables. Temp tables work and allow indexes and if you're going thru the trouble of creating a table variable, why would you "hate" temp tables? I usually will try a few of your options and look at the execution plan in my favorite SQL Sentry Plan Explorer (https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) to make sure i'm actually using the query with the best plan that will scale as data grows.

Comment: I mostly hate them because I have to check if they exist first and drop them if they do and remember to drop them when I'm done and then if I have a stored proc that runs every 2 mintues I have to worry that the last one didn't finish before I started this one and then I can't have 2 temp tables with the same name so I might be dropping a temp table that is actually still being used.

Comment: And then when I'm testing/troubleshooting I constantly get the "table already exists" error.  Table variables don't have those problems.

Comment: So in a nutshell, I don't like the maintenance they represent.

Comment: True, but table variables SUUUUUCK for performance unless you have only one record in it. Also, do this as your fist line... problem solved. IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableName') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableName

Comment: Well of course, but that doesn't work very well with my testing/troubleshooting style.

Comment: LORD HAVE MERCY.  I can't even `INSERT` into a table variable without it taking 5 - 10 times longer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure my underlying question has been answered (how best to join the open ended rate table); but ultimately I cared about performance and changing all the table variables I was using to temp tables has accomplished that.